# How do I extend the lifetime of T in Option<T>

Tags: string, rust, lifetime

I understand that `ip` is scoped in the code block following the match. My understanding is that when that code block exits it will free `ip` so I can't assign it to `server_ip`. How do I get `ip` to live longer?

```
let address_default = "127.0.0.1";
let address = matches.opt_default("i", address_default);

let server_ip = match address {
    Some(ip) => {
        ip.as_slice()
    }
    None => {
        address_default
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`address` is `Option<String>`. You are then proceeding to move `ip` out of it, leaving the reference created by `ip.as_slice()` dangling, as `ip` will be freed at the end of that block.

The primary solution at this level is to keep `address` alive by making `ip` only a *reference* to the `String`, rather than the `String` itself. This is done by changing the `Some(ip)` pattern to `Some(ref ip)`.

You might like http://chrismorgan.info/blog/rust-fizzbuzz.html for some further reading on this specific topic (dealing with owned data and so forth, though not the `Option<T>` part which is unimportant).